# Как убрать ссылку

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте, у меня в сайтбаре выводится три блока: с новыми записями, популярными и связанными. Можно ли как-то сделать что если уже на странице присутствует такая ссылка-то в сайт баре выводилась бы не ссылка, а просто текст.

```
<a href=​"/​oruzhie-v-minecraft-kak-sdelat-mech-luk-i-strely.html">​Оружие в майнкрафте: как сделать меч, лук и стрелы​</a>​
```

А вот так:

```
​Оружие в майнкрафте: как сделать меч, лук и стрелы​
```

Код с сайтбара

1

```
<ul>
    <?php $args=array( 'showposts'=>5, 'meta_key' => 'post_views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ); query_posts($args); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

2

```
<?php $tags=w p_get_post_tags($post->ID); if ($tags) { $tag_ids = array(); foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id; $args=array( 'tag__in' => $tag_ids, // Сортировка происходит по тегам (меткам) 
                                                                                                                  'orderby'=>rand, // Добавляем условие сортировки рандом (случайный подбор) 
                                                                                                                  'caller_get_posts'=>1, // Запрещаем повторение ссылок 
                                                                                                                  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 
                                                                                                                  'showposts'=>5 // Цифра означает количество выводимых записей 
                                                                                                                  ); 
$my_query = new wp_query($args); if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { echo '<ul>'; while ($my_query->have_posts()) { $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php } echo '</ul>'; } wp_reset_query(); } ?>
```

3

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'postbypost', 'limit' => 5, 'format' => 'html' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Если сайдбар ("side bar" *англ.* – боковая панель) генерится уже после страницы с постами, то можно собрать `id` постов на странице в массив, а к в цикле сайдбара проверять, был ли он уже:

    if( in_array( the_ID(), $pagePosts) {
        // был - показать только текст
    } else {
        // не был ещё — показываем как сейчас
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае лучше изменить код, чтобы текущая запись не выводилась, сделать это можно добавив после

> 'orderby'=>rand, // Добавляем условие сортировки рандом (случайный подбор)

следующий код

```
 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), //Не выводить текущую запись
```

Пример можно увидеть [тут](http://site-style.by/kak-vyvesti-poxozhie-zapisi-bez-plagina-wordpress/)

Comment: Вам подходит мой вариант решения или вы всё же хотите использовать свой?